# Can I add a couple of key-value pairs to a JavaScript object as literals in one line?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects, associative-array, key-value

Say I have an object such as

```
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}
```

And I want to add a few more keys without making a loop, something semantically like this:

```
obj += { baz: 3, fred: 4 }
```

Is that possible using an existing JS function? I'd like to do it within some functional-style chaining.

Comment: you want `Object.assign` in modern browsers

Comment: `Object.assign(obj, { baz: 3, fred: 4 });`

Comment: note: for old browsers, (internet exploder) there is a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)

Answer (score 3):

Check if [compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring) is a concern before doing this, but object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to the rescue:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}

obj = {...obj, baz: 3, fred: 4}
```

The following is not possible but we can dream:

```
obj ...= {beef: 5}
```

Comment: Object.assign is more "internet exploder once you use a polyfill" friendly - whereas, this code would need to be transpiled - not criticizing, just a thought

Comment: yea, im gonna add a link to caniuse.com for this

Answer (score 1):

And right after posting my Googling became successful!

Apparently `Object.assign` arrived with ES6 and I'm really looking for modern JS answers.

```
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
}

obj = Object.assign(obj, {baz:3, fred:4})
```

Comment: If you are interested in creating a mutationless object (not always important), try `let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj, { baz:3, fred:4 });` or if you don't mind transpiling or are using recent stable [node](http://node.green/) you can also expand/destructure to `obj = { ...obj, baz:3, fred:4 };`